# Loading a codeigniter view with a form from inside another view

Tags: codeigniter

Using codeigniter, I've been trying to load a view inside of a foreach loop, as follows:

```
$posts = $this->postslibrary->getAllPosts();
foreach($posts as $post){
  $home['content'][$i] = $this->load->view('post', $post['data'], true);
  $i++;
}
$this->load->view('head');
$this->load->view('home', $home);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Each of those post views looks a little like this:

```
<div class="postnum<?=$post_num?>">
  <p>Posted by: <?=$poster_name?></p>
  <p>Reply to: <?=$poster_name?></p>
  <form>
  <input type='text' />
  <input type='submit' />
  </form>
</div>
```

And they're being loaded mostly successfully in the 'home' view (which is below for thoroughness).

```
<div ="posts">
  <?php
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
      echo($content[$i]);
    }
  ?>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <a href='/posts/browse/'>Load more items</a>
</div>
```

But my output ends up looking like:

```
<div class='posts'>
  <div class='postnum1'>
    <p>Posted By: Jim</p>
    <p>Reply to Jim</p>
    <input type='text' />
    <input type='submit' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Why are my form tags not coming through?

Comment: Can you also post php code of your home view file. I wanna see how you work with $home data - problem may lay there.

Comment: have you tried to give your form some attributes ? since and which browser do you use is it chrome ?

Comment: @Aidas I've added the code you requested

Comment: @zaherg I've tried with and without all sorts of attributes. I am using Chrome.

Comment: It might be that you must have an action for your form tag (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3). For something this specific, you should paste your actual code, not what it kinda looks like. Things I would look for: matching opening and closing tags, matching "<" and ">", random quotes from the data. Also programming like this is too complex. Just place your code in the view. Complexity == error prone.

Comment: from what i know about chrome is that he will remove any none standard working attributes and thats happened to me once .. so i think you should try to make your form more standardized as @MichaelOzeryansky said ..

Comment: This just happened to me today and I remembered your question from a day or two ago. I was trying to load a form inside another form and the internal form was getting removed. I don't know if CI was removing it or the browser (although I assume it was the browser). You might check that you are not inadvertently trying to nest forms.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you already have a form around the current form. Chrome is one of the browsers which doesn't accept this and removes the second form. Using a form in a form is bad practice and I suggest you find a different solution to do the form handling.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly left-of-field answer, but have a look at [CodeIgniter Form Generator](http://code.google.com/p/codeigniter-form-generator/).  I've used it a couple of times and it seems pretty good for generating forms from an array.  It's a bit tricky to get your head around it to begin with, but it works well once you've gotten into it.

The basic idea is that you implement a form controller from your ordinary controller, and then just output it in your view file.  It might be a more elegant (and sustainable) solution to what you're trying.